# Count number of equal elements in two numpy array in a given mask

Tags: python, numpy

Given two arrays and a mask, I want to count the intersection of the elements in the two arrays, where the values of the mask are 1.
That is:

```
arr_a = [0 0 0 1 1 3 2 1]
arr_b = [0 0 0 1 2 3 2 1]
mask_ = [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0]
```

The simple intersection between arr_a and arr_b, calculated with the following line is 7.

```
np.sum(arr_a == arr_b)
```

However I want it to be only 4, since I am interested in the identical values inside the mask.
Is there a simple extension to that numpy line to do it elegantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert your mask to a numpy array of `dtype=np.bool`, so that you can use it to filter the arrays, or the equality test itself:

```
import numpy as np

arr_a = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1]
arr_b = [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
mask_ = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]

np.equal(arr_a, arr_b)[np.asarray(mask_, dtype=np.bool)].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **mask** your input arrays, then the most intuitive
approach is to use **masked arrays**.

The first step is to convert your *mask_* (a list of *int*) to a *bool* array,
but with inversion (because *True* in the mask in masked arrays means to
**exclude** the element in question):

```
mask_b = np.invert(np.array(mask_).astype(bool))
```

The result is:

```
array([ True,  True, False, False, False, False, False,  True])
```

The next step is to create both **masked** arrays (*arr_am* and *arr_bm*):

```
arr_am = np.ma.array(arr_a, mask=mask_b)
arr_bm = np.ma.array(arr_b, mask=mask_b)
```

Having both source arrays as **masked** you can run your original code:

```
np.sum(arr_am == arr_bm)
```

or

```
(arr_am == arr_bm).sum()
```